# How to Seriailize an c# object into Json, while using httpClient?

Tags: c#, json, slack-api

I have a little program which should communicate with "Slack". In an older Version I used "`Dictionary<string, string>`" and then put them into `UrlEncodedContent` - which worked fine.
Now I am trying to create a Json-object, using Newtonsoft's Nuget-package and (in my opinion) formatting my object the way they say on their website.
Problem is, when I try to make a simple request, my program just runs to one specific line in the code(`var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);`) and then it just ends. It doesn't throw an exception or display any kind of message, it simply ends on this line. I went through my code step by step while debugging, that's how I know it ends on exactly this line. And I just don't know why!

Now my code: 
First, my object...

```
namespace BPS.Slack
{
    public class JsonObject
    {
        //generally needed parameters
        [JsonProperty("ok")]
        public bool ok { get; set; }    
        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public string error { get; set; }   
        [JsonProperty("channel")]
        public string channel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("token")]
        private string token = "xoxp-MyToken";
        [JsonProperty("as_user")]
        public bool as_user = false;       
        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string username { get;set; } 
        //--------------------------------
        //only needed for textmessages
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string text { get; set; }
        //--------------------------------
        //for posting messages with data attached
        [JsonProperty("initial_comment")]
        public string initial_comment { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("file")]
        public string file { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("channels")]
        public string channels { get; set; }
        //--------------------------------
        //for getting the latest message from a channel
        [JsonProperty("count")]
        public string count = "1";
        [JsonProperty("unreads")]
        public bool unreads = true;
    }
}
```

now the client:

```
   namespace BPS.Slack
    {
        public class BpsHttpClient
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient { };
            public Uri UriMethod { get; set; }

            public BpsHttpClient(string webhookUrl)
            {
                UriMethod = new Uri(webhookUrl);
            }


            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileAsync(MultipartFormDataContent requestContent)
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, UriMethod);
                request.Content = requestContent;
                var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                return response;
            }
        }

    }
```

and the main

```
namespace TestArea
{
    class MainArea
    {
        public static void Main( string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Task.WhenAll(SendMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception ass)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ass);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        private static async Task SendMessage()
        {
            var client = new BpsHttpClient("https://slack.com/api/im.history");
            JsonObject JO = new JsonObject();
            JO.channel = "DCW21NBHD";            
            var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JO);

            var StringJson = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8);
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(StringJson);

            var Response = await client.UploadFileAsync(content);


            string AnswerContent = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(AnswerContent);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

I had the same problem in my older version, BUT only as I wanted to DEserialize an answer I got from Slack. It had to do with my object I tried do deserialize the answer into. But this time I can not figure out what's wrong. But, as I said, I do not have any experience with using serialized objects as Json-property to send requests... anyone has an idea what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT:** This problem is kinda solved. But there is a follow up problem.

Okay, I found out that the reason for the abprubt termination was the

> Task.WhenAll(SendMessage());

it should be

> Task.WaitAll(SendMessage());  Why??? Somebody said I should use WhenAll, but obviously it doesn't work properly in this case...

Now I get a response from Slack, but now a different problem has arisen. When I use this method:

> ```
>     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileAsync(MultipartFormDataContent requestContent)
>     {
>         HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, UriMethod);
>         request.Content = requestContent;
>         var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
>
>         return response;
>     }
> ```

I allways get the answer:

{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_form_data"}

so I tried to explicitly tell it the 'mediaType', I tried "application/json" and others, but with all of them I get the same error. Here is the full method that calls the upper mehtod:

```
 private static async Task SendMessage()
    {
        var client = new BpsHttpClient("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
        JsonObject JO = new JsonObject();
        JO.channel = "DCW21NBHD";
        JO.text = "This is so much fun :D !";
        var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JO, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

        var StringJson = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        requestContent.Add(StringJson);

        var Response = await client.UploadFileAsync(requestContent);

        string AnswerContent = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
```

When I use this method:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(FormUrlEncodedContent content)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(UriMethod, content);

        return response;
    }
```

so bascially I am passing "FormUrlEncodedContent" instead of "MultipartFormDataContent" in this, and then I get the response I want and can work wiht it. BUT this i of little use to me since I have to use "MultipartFormDataContent" to  be able to send files with my requests.

Anyone have an idea what is failing here? Why does it not like the one content-type but the other one? I'd be gratefull for tipps and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You are serializing your object to Json and then adding it to a Multipart body, that's quite strange. Unless you're uploading binary data (eg Files), there is no need to use MultipartFormDataContent.

You are can directly post your `JsonObject` serialized as JSON:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync(StringContent content)
        {                
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            return response;
        }

       var client = new BpsHttpClient("https://slack.com/api/im.history");                  
       JsonObject JO = new JsonObject();
       JO.channel = "DCW21NBHD";            
       var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JO);
       var StringJson = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8);
       var Response = await client.PostJsonAsync(content);
```

Also this is should be POST on the `UploadFileAsync` function.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, UriMethod);
```

Comment: Hey, this doesn't solve the problem. I mean, you were probably right about me not needing to use the MultipartFormDataContent. But it does not change the outcome at all. It still terminates at the exact same point... 
And no, this is a GET-request, so the method should be GET. But my GET-requests also work with the POST-method, in my older version of this.
But yeah, it still doesn't work in this version.

Comment: Multipart body with a GET? I don't think I can help then.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out that in the Main() the problem was this:

```
Task.WhenAll(SendMessage());
```

I should instead use:

```
 Task.WaitAll(SendMessage());
```

Anyone who has more knowledge on this, please elaborate why!

Comment: The reason is that `WhenAll` is not waiting for your async task to complete, but `WaitAll` does. You can also write `SendMessage().Wait();` to wait just for this async method to complete.